# How can I display image it's include in iOS framework?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I found some image include in iOS framework, How can I use this image in my program?

Comment: How is the image in the framework. Images cannot be compiled into static libraries. Which framework are you referring to?

Comment: @HelloWorld What images are you referring to?

Comment: @HelloWorld inside the `UIKIT framework` there is nothing  besides the compiled header files.so your question really ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the images using https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor.

Please note, however, that Apple might not like it if you use their images in your app.
For example, using the GameCenter icon on a custom view/control is prohibited.

If the image is just part of UIKit, it won't be such a big problem, I guess.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No . That's not possible and legal

Because of we cannot use third party and default framework images it's based on the legal issue in AppStore. So better to use control and views. Don't alter default framework images.